# Text to array using XMLHttprequest and javascript

Tags: javascript, text, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to convert a text file into a js array using the line separation. Here is a copy of my code, can someone help?

```
getData('test.txt', 'text', handleSuccess);

    function handleSuccess(data) {
        intoArray(data);
    }

    function intoArray(lines) {
        lineArr = lines.split('\n');
    }

    function createXMLHttpRequest() {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            return new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }

    function getData(url, responseType, successHandler) {
        var xmlhttp = createXMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.responseType = responseType;

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            successHandler(xmlhttp.response, xmlhttp.statusText, xmlhttp);
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    console.log(lineArr);
```

And here is a copy of the text document I have:

```
newsletter.pdf
newsletter
flyer.pdf
flyer
```

The console log returns an empty array. Any Ideas?

Comment: Check the file location and ensure that its url is included correctly in the code.

Comment: Can you share your successHandler code?

Comment: Thank you all, but I figured it out using the page from Alexander.